# TypeError .val() is not a function on my selected answer on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I'm trying to check if the answer selected is correct, if so, then it should add + 1 to my user score. 
But I don't understand why my code doesn't work. Could you please help me where the bug or did I miss something else?

```
 function loadNextQuestion () {
  var selectOption = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
  if (selectOption.val() == questions[answer]) {
    ++userScore;
  } else if (selectOption) {
    ++currentQuestionNum;
    loadQuestion();
    loadQuestionNum();
  } else {
    alert("Please pick an answer.");
  }
};
$("#nextButton").click(loadNextQuestion);
});
```

Comment: Could you please post all of your relevant HTML and JavaScript code? We can't see what `loadQuestion()` and `loadQuestionNum()` are, and we don't see the array `questions` or the variable `answer` either. Please update your post with the relevant code.

Comment: This kind of bugs happens a lot when using the jQuery library. To prevent these problems, make your mind to either prefer jQuery alternative over pure JS or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Your radio button element is not in a jQuery wrapper object, so the jQuery method val() won't work.

Try

```
if(selectOption.value == questions[answer]) {
   ...
}
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it work. I will be more careful not to mix JS and JQuery in the same function

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not working is because you're comparing a Boolean (`selectOption.val()` [which is wrong anyway - it should be `selectOption.value`]) to an element of an array (`questions[answer]`), and then in your `else if` statement you're asking if `selectOption` is true. This code will always run.

Fixing your code only requires you to change this:

```
if (selectOption.val() == questions[answer]) {...}
```

Into something like this:

```
if (selectOption.attr("id") == questions[answer]) {...}
```

With the HTML like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="Chocolate-ice-cream" />
```

And your questions array like this:

```
var questions = ["Chocolate is used in what flavour of ice cream", "Chocolate-ice-cream", ...];
```

Hopefully what I've said makes sense, but please tell me if you don't understand anything.